# Help Modifying RegEx To Return Range of Digits

Tags: regex

Currently this expression `"I ([a-zA-z]\d]{3} "` returns when the following pattern is true:

```
I AAA 
I Z99
```

I need to modify this so it will return a range of alphanumerics after the I from 2 to 13 that do not have a space.

Example:

```
I AAA 
I A321 
I ASHG310310
```

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the quotes:

```
"I ([a-zA-Z\d]{2,13}) "
```

Comment: don't forget the closing paren ")"

Comment: Yeah. I foolishly copied from the question and changed the missing part only because the author stated that this was what he had working. Can't imagine what he has really works.

Comment: I recommend http://regexpal.com/ where you can evaluate your regexps and get instant visual feedback. A real time saver.

Answer (score 2):

The {} brackets allow two parameters seperated by a comma, which indicates the minimum and maximum number of repetitions.  Also, I'm not sure if your original regex gets what you intend - as it's written, it accepts 3 groups of a letter and a number.

You may want to try

```
I ([a-zA-Z]|\d){2,13}
```

There's a reference page here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: It's much more efficient to put the \d inside the character class, like Tomalak did.